# Solving an equation without product log function (Lambert's W function)

Tags: logarithms, special-functions, lambert-w

I want to find x value without using product log function (Lambert's W function).

$$x\ln x = 1$$

Comment: I want to solve $x^2 = -1$ without using complex numbers...

Comment: If you really want a closed form of the solution, this is what Lambert's W-function _does_. Otherwise, you can always solve the equation numerically or graphically...

Comment: @StackTD so how I can solve it numerically ?

Comment: @smail, try [Newton's method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method) with $f(x) = x\ln x - 1$.

Comment: @smail You either use a computer (websites, software ...) or pick one of many [numerical methods](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numerical_analysis#Solving_equations_and_systems_of_equations).

Comment: Look I'm trying to specify the intersection of curve with X axis I know the result is (1,763) but I do not how to count it

Comment: The solution to this is $1/\Omega$ , where $\Omega$ is defined at the Wikipedia article, but is essentially defined in terms of $W(1)$. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Omega_constant

Comment: What curve with the $x$-axis, and do you want to approximate it, or do you want to represent it?

Comment: @ThomasAndrews I want to represent

Comment: Then you need Lambert, or $\Omega$, which is based on Lambert. No other way.

Comment: So how I can study the intersection of curve with X axis ?
I'm just I student in high school I never learn Lambert's W-function

Comment: You can use its integral/series representations